# Alexa Skill Management - ASK CLI

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

When I run 'ask init' a login browser page is opened. I login with my amazon account, and I am getting a Success message, but in the console I am getting the next error:

Call list-vendors error.
    Error code: 401
    {
    "message": "You are not authorized to access this operation."
    }

Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you set you AWS credentials?

Comment: I have set up my AWS account and did everything required for the set up.

Comment: same issue here. Seems that there is a general problem?! Let me know if you solve it

Answer (score 1):

I solved this now by:
First installing and configuring aws cli:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html

Completing my (AWS Root Account) developer profile at developer.amazon.com

Comment: Yes, I also solved this issue by completing my Amazon Developer profile at developer.amazon.com

Answer (score 0):

I have a developer account and a personal account. I was trying to connect my personal account instead of my developer account, so when I connected my developer account, i solved the problem.